# Using multiple body classes to setup calls on subclasses

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am working on a website that was built four or five years ago and I ran across something that I have never seen before. Who ever built the site is using both classes (.home.product) to call any sub-elements (.banner) in the page. I didn't think you could do this, but obviously it works. Is this a hack or is it kosher? If this is ok to do can you also do it with an ID? (Example: #home.product)? I hope my question makes sense.

```
<head>           
<style>     
.home.product .banner{
 background:#d1d1d1;
 border:solid 1px #000;
 width:500px;
 height:150px;
 }
</style>     
</head>    
<body class="home product">  
  <div class="banner">Blah Blah Blah</div>   
</body>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: yes you can use an id  as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly valid and normal to [specify multiple classes on a single HTML element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-class), and to target them with [multiple, chained class selectors in CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#class-html). There's nothing hacky about it at all.

And yes, you can also chain any number of ID selectors, class selectors, attribute selectors and pseudo-classes with one another in any order. Both `#home.product` and `.product#home` are equivalent, matching an element with an ID of `home` as well as a `product` class.